# action column in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1

Is there `xtype : actioncolumn` in sencha touch like extjs 4.1  for column config ? if not, then what is there in sencha touch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

> In Sencha Touch, we can use  Ext.field.select

For more details you can refer this link :

> http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Select

Comment: hey, khushbu..Thanks ! I was looking for given above answer. :)